# How to compare records in a dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For example I have a `dataframe` as below:

```
var tmp_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("One", "Sagar", 1), 
  ("Two", "Ramesh" , 2), 
  ("Three", "Suresh", 3), 
  ("One", "Sagar", 5)
)).toDF("ID", "Name", "Balance");
```

Now I want to write all records from above dataframe having same ID in one file likewise. Please advise.

Comment: you can write the entire DF in single file and as a post processing, you can use awk tools to split them based on "ID" column into different files... similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409462/hive-how-to-extract-data-and-write-to-local-files-based-on-column-value/52428391#52428391

Answer (score 0):

```
//find records having same id and rename the id column to idstowrite
val idsMoreThanOne = tmp_df.groupBy('id).count.filter('count.gt(1)).withColumnRenamed("id" , "idstowrite")
idsMoreThanOne.show
//join back with original dataframe
val joinedDf = idsMoreThanOne.join(tmp_df ,tmp_df("id") === idsMoreThanOne("idstowrite") , "left")
joinedDf.show
//select only the columns we want
val dfToWrite = joinedDf.select("id" , "Name" , "Balance")
dfToWrite.show
```

[image: result dataframe]