# Hive How to extract data and write to local files based on column value

Tags: sql, database, shell, hadoop, hive

I am trying to extract data from Hive table and write to local files:

One output file per a column "Date" value. My Hive table will have about 2+ years history of data, that means I will need about 700+ different output files.

My current knowledge will only allow me to write one file per a run, this is my code can be run in Hive command line:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/local/hive/temp'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
select date, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
from WH_TEMP_EXTRACT.table_temp
where date='2015-09-17';
```

I am not a developer, but currently in the process of researching all options to perform this task.  I appreciate any help you can provide here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract all the 2 year data in a single query into the local file. After that you can use awk command to get them into individual files as below.

```
/tmp/hive> ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxxx yyyyyy 228 Sep 20 10:11 hive_extract.dat
/tmp/hive> cat hive_extract.dat
2018-09-17,abc,134
2018-09-17,abc,135
2018-09-17,abc,136
2018-09-17,abc,137
2018-09-17,abc,138
2018-09-18,abc,141
2018-09-18,abc,142
2018-09-18,abc,143
2018-09-18,abc,144
2018-09-19,abc,150
2018-09-19,abc,151
2018-09-19,abc,152
/tmp/hive> awk -F"," '{ print $0 > "file_"$1 }' hive_extract.dat
/tmp/hive> ll
total 28
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxxx yyyyyy 228 Sep 20 10:11 hive_extract.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxxx yyyyyy  57 Sep 20 10:13 file_2018-09-19
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxxx yyyyyy  76 Sep 20 10:13 file_2018-09-18
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxxx yyyyyy  95 Sep 20 10:13 file_2018-09-17
/tmp/hive> cat file_2018-09-17
2018-09-17,abc,134
2018-09-17,abc,135
2018-09-17,abc,136
2018-09-17,abc,137
2018-09-17,abc,138
/tmp/hive> cat file_2018-09-18
2018-09-18,abc,141
2018-09-18,abc,142
2018-09-18,abc,143
2018-09-18,abc,144
/tmp/hive> cat file_2018-09-19
2018-09-19,abc,150
2018-09-19,abc,151
2018-09-19,abc,152
/tmp/hive>
```

let me know if this solution will work for you.

**EDIT 1:**
use gsub

```
awk -F"," '{ gsub("-","_",$1); print $0 > "file_"$1 }' hive_extract.dat
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS=","} { gsub("-","_",$1); print $0 > "file_"$1 }' hive_extract.dat
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
awk -F"," '{ fx=$1;gsub("-","_",fx);print $0 > "file_"fx }' hive_extract.dat
```

Comment: Hi, this is a good approach, thank you.  I have one question on this command, awk -F"," '{ print $0 > "file_"$1 }' hive_extract.dat,   how can I change the new output file naming convention to "file_YYYY_MM_DD"?  the date column from the data has dash "-" between the YYYY MM DD,  that can't be changed.  How to change the output file to use underline "_" link between YYYY MM DD?

Comment: that is easy. use gsub and convert the "-" to "_" as below  awk -F"," '{ gsub("-","_",$1); print $0 > "file_"$1 }' hive_extract.dat

Comment: your code does rename the new file but it also removed the comma delimiter within the data,  how to modify it to keep the data as-is?    awk -F "," '{ gsub("-","_",$1); print $0 > "file_"$1 }' hive_extract.dat

Comment: e.g.,  comma was removed in the data.    20180917 abc 134

Comment: great! thanks for your help.. I need to learn more linux command now.. >.

Comment: Hi @stack0114106,  sorry, me again.  I found out your Edit 2 code has a small bug, the output file name does have the under line yyyy_mm_dd,  but this code changed the data contents, now the date field in the data has the underline instead of original yyyy-mm-dd format...   I want to keep data as-is and only change the new output files name.

Comment: Thanks it worked!! I have one more question, can you see my Edit section in original question?  sorry I am new to the shell script so still learning.